# Sitecore:how to get workflow items programmatically

Tags: c#, workflow, sitecore, sitecore-workflow

i have assigned workflow as usual. i tried following code but didn't get any item....please share any sample code if you have any or help me get items

```
Database masterDatabase = Factory.GetDatabase("master");

Item currentItem = masterDatabase.Items["/sitecore/content/Home"];

IWorkflow workflow = masterDatabase.WorkflowProvider.GetWorkflow(currentItem);

WorkflowState state = workflow.GetState(currentItem);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use SecurityDisabler

```
using (new SecurityDisabler())
{
     var db= Factory.GetDatabase("master");
     var item = db.Items["/sitecore/content/Home"];         
     // getting the item's workflow reference
     var wf = this.database.WorkflowProvider.GetWorkflow(item);         
     // here we need either to login as a user with appropriate permissions
     // to have access to workflow states/commands or disable security
     wf.Start(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That API is only going to work in a site context where workflow is enabled.  Either enable it in your  `<sites>` config or use a context switching block around your code.